# Highlight Function Calls Sublime Text (python)

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I would like to be able to find a way to color **the name of function calls** in python with a different color. This behavior is found for the C language, but not for Python. that's why I think it should be possible to do it.

Edit:

I'm not looking for the Color Scheme syntax specific, I'm rather looking for the specific lines I would have to add to the Python.tmLanguage.

After trying the suggestion by jdi, I ended up with this:

[image]

What I would like would be only array to be colored differently, not the parenthesis, objects calling methods, etc ...

Comment: Ok when you say highlight, do you mean all time, or the selected color? Because I cannot figure out what is missing from my answer. You somehow have a Python.tmLanguage that does not contain those already existing pattern defs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have so far it is not perfect but it kinda works:

I took this piece from the C.tmLanguage file that comes bundled in every ST2 and added a few things so that this can be colored differently from some of the default functions in Python defined in the Python.tmLanguage file:

```
    <dict>
        <key>captures</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>punctuation.whitespace.function-call.leading.python</string>
            </dict>
            <key>2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>support.function.any-method.python</string>
            </dict>
            <key>3</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>punctuation.definition.parameters.python</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>match</key>
        <string>(?x) (?: (?= \s )  (?:(?&lt;=else|new|return) | (?&lt;!\w)) (\s+))?
(\b
    (?!(while|for|do|if|else|switch|catch|enumerate|return|r?iterate|
        __import__|all|abs|any|apply|callable|chr|cmp|coerce|compile|delattr|dir|
        divmod|eval|execfile|filter|getattr|globals|hasattr|hash|hex|id|
        input|intern|isinstance|issubclass|iter|len|locals|map|max|min|oct|
        ord|pow|range|raw_input|reduce|reload|repr|round|setattr|sorted|
        sum|unichr|vars|zip|basestring|bool|buffer|classmethod|complex|dict|enumerate|file|
        float|frozenset|int|list|long|object|open|property|reversed|set|
        slice|staticmethod|str|super|tuple|type|unicode|xrange|
        abs|add|and|call|cmp|coerce|complex|contains|del|delattr|
        delete|delitem|delslice|div|divmod|enter|eq|exit|float|
        floordiv|ge|get|getattr|getattribute|getitem|getslice|gt|
        hash|hex|iadd|iand|idiv|ifloordiv|ilshift|imod|imul|init|
        int|invert|ior|ipow|irshift|isub|iter|itruediv|ixor|le|len|
        long|lshift|lt|mod|mul|ne|neg|new|nonzero|oct|or|pos|pow|
        radd|rand|rdiv|rdivmod|repr|rfloordiv|rlshift|rmod|rmul|ror|
        rpow|rrshift|rshift|rsub|rtruediv|rxor|set|setattr|setitem|
        setslice|str|sub|truediv|unicode|xor
    )\s*\()(?:(?!NS)[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*+\b | :: )++                  # actual name
)
 \s*(\()</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>meta.function-call.python</string>
    </dict>
```

And this is how the output looks like using the Monokai Bright theme, although it is very subtle you can notice how `open` is formatted different to `array`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You will need to edit an existing theme, or duplicate one, modify it, and set to that... Then you can add something like this to the bottom:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Function call</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>meta.function-call - punctuation - meta.function-call.arguments</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF0000</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

This takes the function-call pattern, and subtracts the subsets for the parenthesis of the call, leaving just the name.

Default themes are located in: `Packages/Color Scheme - Default`

[image: Highlighted Text example]

Comment: Works for me! Make sure you are set to use that theme in the app

Comment: Sorry my question was very vague, although this helps this is not what I'm entirely looking for. Though thanks!

Comment: I dont understand how this doesnt solve it though. The color syntax only works based on the fact that those patterns are already defined in tmLanguage. Search "function-call". The theme is simply visualizing the pattern. You are just as free to write a plugin using the same names that the color syntax is using to refer to them.

Comment: I have searched through my Python.tmLanguage file and could find nothing. Therefore adding these lines make no effect as the coloring is set on whatever matches the equivalent tag in the tmLanguage.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an updated st2? I dont understand how I could have those syntax defs in my Python.tmLanguage and not you. There are a few places where it defines the actual function defs and a few where it defines function-call.

Comment: I'm using an updated version of ST2 (the last one I think). As a matter of fact you are right, that syntax does highlight a function call but I'm looking for the way to highlight the name of a function call. Sorry for not being clear from the beginning, this was my fault.

Comment: http://gitcafe.com/ltn/ST2-config-mac/blob/master/Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage#code. Line 698

Comment: Wow. This whole time you could have easily said you wanted that without the parenthesis. It sounded like you wanted something absolutely different

Comment: @ElDeveloper: There ya go! Using the example of your screenshot

Comment: Sorry for not being clear from the beginning. Still, it is highlighting methods and the objects :S